# MFC Getting Dialog Area

Tags: mfc

I created a common dialog class(CCommonDlg) inherited from CDialogEx.

Now I am inheriting CMyDialog from CCommonDialog. Passed CMyDialog dialog resource ID to base class CCommonDialog.I am trying to draw a circle on the dialog. So in `CMyDialog::OnPaint()` I tried the below code:

```
CPaintDC dc(this);
CRect rect;
GetWindowRect(&rect);
ScreenToClient(rect);
dc.Ellipse(rect);
```

While running i am seeing a part of the bigger circle. Its not fitting to the dialog. So i believe GetWindowRect is not giving me proper dialog dimension.

Can anyone please help on this.
NOTE: CommonDlg is one DLL and CMyDlg is anther dll.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

```
CPaintDC dc(this);
CRect rect;
GetClientRect(&rect);  //to get client area only
dc.Ellipse(rect);
```

the function you are using, `GetWindowRect(&rect);`
It will include title bar of your window also, so in that area your `Ellipse` will be clipped. So as you need to draw on client area only, you should use `GetClientRect(&rect);`